# Where is the place of "public static void Main(string[] args)" in the Program.cs file in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: .net

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 6.0 framework. The following no longer exists in the `Program.cs` file

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope=host.Services.CreateScope());
...
```

How can I add these:

```cs
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
using (var scope=host.Services.CreateScope());
```

Comment: How have you created the Program.cs file? What *is* there instead? There's a new console app template that uses top-level statements - but that comes with an explanatory link at the top. If that's what you've got, you should read that link.

Comment: Fundamentally, you can still write that code, just without declaring a Program class or a Main method. Or you can declare it manually like you used to... it's just a template.

Comment: @JonSkeet - are you sure about the separate template? All I'm seeing in VS is a checkbox in the template wizard to allow top-level statements or not; I'm seeing it in  multiple project types (at least console and, as here, web apps)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I didn't say it was a *separate* template. It's just new in terms of "it's different than the old console app template". I don't know whether there's a way of creating a new console app using the old template.

Comment: You can just type the code directly into your program.cs file. In .NET 6, they have removed the Main method and the default using statements. Instead, you just type code directly. You can check this link for reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-net-6-0-console-application/

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try the recommended suggestions

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is [creation of a minimal console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) (in terms of code) in .NET 6.0 or perhaps a minimal Web API if you used that project template. It looks like you may be trying to create a [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

> As noted in the comments by @Damien_The_Unbeliever you can use the template that features a `Main()` by selecting **Do note use top-level statements** in the **Aditional Information** dialog. This will add the `Main()` and other ceremony code automatically upon creation of the solution. (This was recently added; update VS if you don't have it).

In any case, As Jon Skeet said, a .NET 6.0 file template is used to generate the `Program.cs` file, and it is the compiler that recognizes the new minimal footprint. Depending on which project template you used, you will have some top-level statements that you can delete (if appropriate) and place your code.

If you've used the minimal template and are ok with it, you add your lines of code directly in `Program.cs`. These lines when compiled will belong to `Main()`.

So you can enter just

```cs
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope());

// this will end up as a local function to Main()
IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    // of course, not null here. This is pseudo-code-ish
    return null;
}
```

and you're done! This, when compiled, will end up looking like this C#

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope());

            // this will end up as a local function to Main()
            IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            {
                // of course, not null here. This is pseudo-code-ish
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you accidentally used the minimal template and later prefer the older template, you can manually add the non-minimal code by pasting or typing it in directly to `Program.cs`. There's some magic here as both forms are supported. What's really interesting is you can then strip out, one by one, the following, and all forms compile, and all forms yield the same C# representation above (roughly speaking... the IL may be slightly different in each case).

- remove the usings (still compiles)
- remove the class (still compiles)
- remove the Main method (still compiles)

So the short answer is that Main is *still* there and *still* in a class; you just can't see it.

To be completely honest, though, I would not even try to paste in the ceremonial code. Just go with your own, few, necessary lines.

Comment: Am I the only one who sees the "Do not use top-level statements" checkbox in the "Additional Information" stage of creating a project using these templates that lets you easily switch which version is generated and without having to mess around with target frameworks, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it appears I'm using an older version of VS 2022. Time to update! I had not seen that yet.